# Extract text between two XML tags using sed

Tags: xml, regex, linux, shell, sed

I have XML file similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OnlineCommentary>
    <doc docid="cnn_210085_comment002" articleURL="http://www.cnn.com/News.asp?NewsID=210085" date="10/07/2010" time="00:21" subtitle="Is Justin Bieber getting special treatment?" author="Zorro75">
        <seg id="1"> They are the same thing. Let's shoot them both. </seg>
    </doc>
    <doc docid="cnn_210092_comment004" articleURL="http://www.cnn.com/News.asp?NewsID=210092" date="06/04/2010" time="17:07" subtitle="Dear Chicago, we love you despite it all" author="MRL1313">
        <seg id="1"> We can't wait for you to move back either. </seg>
        <seg id="2"> You seem quite uptight. </seg>
        <seg id="3"> Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more? </seg>
    </doc>
</OnlineCommentary>
```

I would like to to execute command on this file to extract only the contnet between the opening tag `<seg ...>` and the closing tag `</seg>`

I tried :

```
sed -n 's:.*<seg id="1">\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' XML-file.xml > output.txt
```

My questions are the following:

-- How can I print all `<seg id="*">`?? my command prints only the the content of the first tag (`<seg id="*">`)

-- Is that is there a way that can be used to make for example the `<seg id="1">`, `<seg id="2">`, `<seg id="3">` to be printed in the same line while the tag that include only `<seg id="1">` to be printed in separate line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print all the `<seg id=>` (one per line) including `<seg`

```
sed -n 's:.*\(<seg id="[0-9]\{1,\}">.*</seg>\).*:\1:p' XML-file.xml > output.txt
```

Print all on 1 line with separated `,`. Use of holding buffer instead of printing and at the end, recall the buffer, replace new line by `,` (and remove starting `,` due to Append action), and print the result

```
sed -n '\:.*\(<seg id="[0-9]\{1,\}">.*</seg>\).*:  { s//\1/
   H
   }
$ {g
   s/\n/,/g;s/^,//
   p
   }' XML-file.xml > output.txt
```

Now, the advice of @Choroba to use adequat XML tools is very good, you minimize the risk of treating unwanted data of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML handling tool. For example, in [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
for //doc echo seg/text() ;
```